# How to add to cells and return the result inthe third cell in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

say, i have the following data

```
A  B  C
3  5  
4  8  
5  9  
6  0  
7  6  
8  3  
9  4
```

How can i add two cells from each line and put the result in the cloumn C, the result should look like this..

```
A  B  C
3  5  8
4  8  12
5  9  14
6  0  6
7  6  13
8  3  11
9  4  13
```

thank you

Comment: SO is for programming questions - please clarify whether you need to do this programmatically, or are just stuck on how to use Excel.

Comment: well, i'd like to do it using the function in MS Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write: `=(A1 + B1)` in cell C1.
then select the cell, there's a little square in one of the corners, click it and drag down.

Comment: select the C1 cell, it will put a "frame" around it, one of the corners has a little square, click it and drag down. this will apply the same formula for the rest of the cells.

Comment: Is there anyway to do that just by typing  in the formula bar instead of dragging down? *actully i've more than 10,000 cells in both A1 and B1, so dragging is kinda hard*

Comment: double click the little square instead of dragging it. the formula will be copied down as far as your goes.

Answer (score 1):

In cell C1 (assuming that `3,5` line is row 1), enter `=a1+b1` and hit ENTER.

Then click in that cell, grab the bottom right corner of it and drag/extend it to the seventh row.

Comment: Is there anyway to do that just by typing  in the formula bar instead of dragging down?